# Scrape text inside div tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape some basic data. The parts of the source code I need are:

```
<div class="header-team">Team name 1</div>

<div class="header-team">Team name 2</div>
```

The two lines are not next to each other.

I am trying this:

```
for team in soup.findAll('div', 'header-team')
    print team
```

But get all the code returned. I have tried adding on .text but it returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working to me-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = """<div class="header-team">Team name 1</div>

<div class="header-team">Team name 2</div>"""

soup = bs(data,'lxml')

for team in soup.findAll('div', 'header-team'):
    print team.text
```

Output-

```
Team name 1
Team name 2
```